How to use fromJson factory from a generic class generated by Freezed?
I use the Freezed package in my Flutter app to generate REST API models. Everything is okay BUT I can't get how to use a generated fromJson factory for generic classes.
For example, I have a paginating model:
import 'package:freezed_annotation/freezed_annotation.dart';
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';

// required: associates our `main.dart` with the code generated by Freezed
part 'page.freezed.dart';

// But if Person was not serializable, we could skip it.
part 'page.g.dart';

@Freezed(genericArgumentFactories: true)
class Page<TItem> with _$Page<TItem> {
  const factory Page({
    required int count,
    required String? next,
    required String? previous,
    required List<TItem> results,
  }) = _Page;

  factory Page.fromJson(
          Map<String, dynamic> json, TItem Function(Object?) fromJsonT) =>
      _$PageFromJson(json, fromJsonT);
}

And a page item model:
import 'package:freezed_annotation/freezed_annotation.dart';
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';

// required: associates our `main.dart` with the code generated by Freezed
part 'post.freezed.dart';
// But if Person was not serializable, we could skip it.
part 'post.g.dart';

@freezed
class Post with _$Post {
  const factory Post({
    required int id,
    required String channelLogoUri,
    required String channelName,
    required String body,
  }) = _Post;

  factory Post.fromJson(Map<String, Object?> json) => _$PostFromJson(json);
}

So, how do I expect to use it?.
import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:http/http.dart';
import 'package:myapp/data/models/post.dart';
import 'package:myapp/data/models/page.dart';

class PostsRepository {
  static const int pageSize = 25;

  Future<Page<Post>?> fetchPosts() async {
    final client = Client();
    final uri = Uri.parse('https://myapp.site/posts');
    final response = await client.get(uri);
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      final map = json.decode(const Utf8Decoder().convert(response.bodyBytes));
      return Page.fromJson(map, Post.fromJson);
    }
    return null;
  }
}

Easy-peasy! However, this code won't work... The problem is in signatures of these factory methods:

Page: fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json, TItem Function(Object?) fromJsonT)
Post: fromJson(Map<String, Object?> json)

I don't know how to convert Object? into Map<String, Object?> safely. Also I can't get why can the Object in TItem Function(Object?) fromJsonT be null? What's for?

please check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64198719/generic-class-in-flutter.

@chunhunghan, thank you!
